# Styles not working as expected

Tags: html, css, svg

It still does it with **px** included or not included in it.

How would I add this to style up at the top, and for it to work?

It works **like this:**

https://jsfiddle.net/fwewpLa5/40/

```
<svg class="play" width="39" height="40" style="margin: 2px 284px;"
<svg class="pause" width="39" height="40" style="margin: 2px 284px;"
```

[image]

I tried doing something **like this:**

https://jsfiddle.net/fwewpLa5/46/

```
  .button div {
    width: 39;
    height: 40;
    margin: 2px 284px;
  }
```

[image]

**and this:**

https://jsfiddle.net/fwewpLa5/47/

```
  .button {
    width: 39;
    height: 40;
    margin: 2px 284px;
  }
```

[image]

But neither one of those work.

Does anyone know how I can get it to work?

Comment: you missing units `px`

Comment: It still does it with that included in it. That makes no difference at all.

Comment: ah i see, it's SVG didn't pay attention

Comment: 'to style up at the top' - can you explain what you mean with that phrase in different words?

Answer (score 0):

Add the CSS like this:

```
  .button .play {
    width: 39px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 2px 284px;
  }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/89h2hzmg/)